# Nested Div container breaking flex wrap

Tags: html, css

I have several nested `<div>` containers within my html code set to flex wrap. So far it's worked fine until I get to the footer, where I nest those containers within another `<div>` container. When I do this, the wrapping for the css breaks and it makes a row where the images are on and combines with an `<hr>`, then each nested div within it acts as if it is a block and stacks vertically. I can't figure out why the wrapping breaks. I've tried changing the final `<div>` containers to `<section>` and other containers but nothing changes. Below is the code

```
.hr2{
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 98%);
}

  .pic-left{
    float: left;
  }

  .pic-right{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

    .page {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .section {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .fmenu-container {
      background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 98%);
      margin: 0 0 140px 0;
    }

    .fmenu {
      color: gray;
      font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: left;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .fmenu-1 {
      margin-left: 100px;
    }

    .fmenu-1,
    .fmenu-2,
    .fmenu-3,
    .fmenu-4 {
      width: 310px;
    }
```

```
    <div class="page">
      <div class="section fmenu-container">
        <!--footer menu-->
        <img class="pic-left" src="images\logo.svg" alt="Insure-logo">
        <img class="pic-right" src="images\icon-instagram.svg" alt="instagram">
        <img class="pic-right" src="images\icon-pinterest.svg" alt="pinterest">
        <img class="pic-right" src="images\icon-twitter.svg" alt="twitter">
        <img class="pic-right" src="images\icon-facebook.svg" alt="facebook">
        <hr class="hr2">
        <div class="fmenu fmenu-1">
          Our company<br>
          <br>
          <a class="flink" href="#">How we work<br></a>
          <a class="flink" href="#">Why Insure?<br></a>
          <a class="flink" href="#">View plans<br></a>
          <a class="flink" href="#">Reviews<br></a>
        </div>
        <div class="fmenu fmenu-2">
          Help me<br>
          <br>
          <a class="flink" href="#">FAQ<br></a>
          <a class="flink" href="#">Terms of use<br></a>
          <a class="flink" href="#">Privacy policy<br></a>
          <a class="flink" href="#">Cookies<br></a>
        </div>
        <div class="fmenu fmenu-3">
          Contact<br>
          <br>
          <a class="flink" href="#">Sales<br></a>
          <a class="flink" href="#">Support<br></a>
          <a class="flink" href="#">Live chat<br></a>
        </div>
        <div class="fmenu fmenu-4">
          Others<br>
          <br>
          <a class="flink" href="#">Careers<br></a>
          <a class="flink" href="#">Press<br></a>
          <a class="flink" href="#">Licenses<br></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, only your `.page` is flex which makes `.section` flex child. Everything inside of `.section` has nothing to do with flex

Comment: And most likely `.page` probably doesn't need to be flex, over use of flex is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

The separation seems to indicate that social media menu and the footer are two different `div` containers. The code will be fixed the following way

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
}

.fmenu-container {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 98%);
  margin: 0 0 140px 0;
}

.fmenu-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.fmenu {
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fmenu-1 {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.fmenu-1,
.fmenu-2,
.fmenu-3,
.fmenu-4 {
  width: 310px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="section fmenu-container">
    <!--footer menu-->
    <img class="pic-left" src="images\logo.svg" alt="Insure-logo">
    <img class="pic-right" src="images\icon-instagram.svg" alt="instagram">
    <img class="pic-right" src="images\icon-pinterest.svg" alt="pinterest">
    <img class="pic-right" src="images\icon-twitter.svg" alt="twitter">
    <img class="pic-right" src="images\icon-facebook.svg" alt="facebook">
    <hr class="hr2">
    <div class="fmenu-wrapper">
      <div class="fmenu fmenu-1">
        Our company<br>
        <br>
        <a class="flink" href="#">How we work<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Why Insure?<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">View plans<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Reviews<br></a>
      </div>
      <div class="fmenu fmenu-2">
        Help me<br>
        <br>
        <a class="flink" href="#">FAQ<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Terms of use<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Privacy policy<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Cookies<br></a>
      </div>
      <div class="fmenu fmenu-3">
        Contact<br>
        <br>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Sales<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Support<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Live chat<br></a>
      </div>
      <div class="fmenu fmenu-4">
        Others<br>
        <br>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Careers<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Press<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Licenses<br></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But it could be made better the following way

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
}

.fmenu-container {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 98%);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.fmenu {
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fmenu-1 {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.fmenu-1,
.fmenu-2,
.fmenu-3,
.fmenu-4 {
  width: 310px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section fmenu-container">
  <!--footer menu-->
  <img class="pic-left" src="images\logo.svg" alt="Insure-logo">
  <img class="pic-right" src="images\icon-instagram.svg" alt="instagram">
  <img class="pic-right" src="images\icon-pinterest.svg" alt="pinterest">
  <img class="pic-right" src="images\icon-twitter.svg" alt="twitter">
  <img class="pic-right" src="images\icon-facebook.svg" alt="facebook">
</div>
<hr class="hr2">
<div class="section fmenu-container">
  <div class="fmenu fmenu-1">
    Our company<br>
    <br>
    <a class="flink" href="#">How we work<br></a>
    <a class="flink" href="#">Why Insure?<br></a>
    <a class="flink" href="#">View plans<br></a>
    <a class="flink" href="#">Reviews<br></a>
  </div>
  <div class="fmenu fmenu-2">
    Help me<br>
    <br>
    <a class="flink" href="#">FAQ<br></a>
    <a class="flink" href="#">Terms of use<br></a>
    <a class="flink" href="#">Privacy policy<br></a>
    <a class="flink" href="#">Cookies<br></a>
  </div>
  <div class="fmenu fmenu-3">
    Contact<br>
    <br>
    <a class="flink" href="#">Sales<br></a>
    <a class="flink" href="#">Support<br></a>
    <a class="flink" href="#">Live chat<br></a>
  </div>
  <div class="fmenu fmenu-4">
    Others<br>
    <br>
    <a class="flink" href="#">Careers<br></a>
    <a class="flink" href="#">Press<br></a>
    <a class="flink" href="#">Licenses<br></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm they do fix the seperate fmenus stacking vertically, but the horizontal line still just lines up at the top and it ignores all spacing and margins for the images. I forgot to include those classes in my code, I'll include those now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a parent container with flex properties

```
<!--Add new parent div with flex properties -->
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div class="fmenu fmenu-1">
        Our company
        <br>
        <br>
        <a class="flink" href="#">How we work<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Why Insure?<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">View plans<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Reviews<br></a>
    </div>

    <div class="fmenu fmenu-2">
        Help me
        <br>
        <br>
        <a class="flink" href="#">FAQ<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Terms of use<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Privacy policy<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Cookies<br></a>
    </div>

    <div class="fmenu fmenu-3">
        Contact
        <br>
        <br>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Sales<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Support<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Live chat<br></a>
    </div>

    <div class="fmenu fmenu-4">
        Others
        <br>
        <br>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Careers<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Press<br></a>
        <a class="flink" href="#">Licenses<br></a>
    </div>

</div>
<!---end parent div-->
```